# NodeJS - npm install dependencies

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to setup an app with nodejs and express, after

> CMD npm install

I recive:

npm WARN unmet depedency C:\node\app...\send requires on-finished@'2.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet depedency C:\node\app...\on-finished

[image]

Comment: Try `npm install -g on-finished@2.1.0`. I have not tested this yet, but I believe that a dependency of your app requires that specific version, and it cannot install it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZLkG2sy.png But when I go to localhost:3000 'PAGE NOT AVAILABLE'

Comment: are there any errors in your console? No warnings? Also, this new error might be an issue with your app itself.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
http://localhost:3000/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS And this is my package.json - http://pastebin.com/8wdbpsMv

Comment: You should check your app itself. It seems the web server is not starting, or at least not actually properly opening itself on port 3000.

Comment: I just follwed these steps, what should I check? http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

Comment: I am not familiar with mongoDB, or with this particular style of express.js setup. You should probably follow @Paul 's answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67761/discussion-between-user3053430-and-hiero).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your mongodb instance is not running.  Make sure you have it started before trying to start your app or going to one of your pages.

Comment: Can you explain how do to that?

Comment: How is MongoDB related to an npm install?

Comment: how to install mongodb

Comment: @try-catch-finally it's not, the npm stuff was warnings.  The actual error he got was (I suspect) an error on not connecting to mongodb.

Comment: @hiero check out the docs. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/